# Automatically build cocoa pods for Xcode Workspace

Tags: ios, xcode

Just wanted to know what is the best way/place to run `pod install` or `pod update` so that each time when I build the project in Xcode, the command runs automatically.

I tried with putting `pod install` in Xcode Project -> Scheme -> Pre-actions, but was not able to see any output. Is there any other better way?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I am pretty sure you'll have to build/run your program repeatedly during development and executing `pod install` will slow it down drastically.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it will slow down, but I want to implement this only for 'Release' configuration. We'll keep running/debugging our app while developing in 'Debug'.